# Flutter NamedRoutes from LoginScreen to HomeScreen using custom widget not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to go from one screen to another.

In my Login_screen I have two buttons that I want to navigate to the next screen when tapped. A "LOGIN" button and a "REGISTER BUTTON"

When I use Navigator.pushName from inside a "LOGIN" Textbutton. Everything works fine and I am able to go to the homescreen.id. However However when i use my own custom widget called RoundedButton it doesn't work (which i extracted from the textButton).

[image]

here is the code for my Roundedbutton()

[image]

here is my main.dart file for reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'screens/registration_screen.dart';
import 'screens/home_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'test app';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      initialRoute: LoginScreen.id,
      routes: {
        LoginScreen.id : (context) => const LoginScreen(),
        RegistrationScreen.id : (context) => const RegistrationScreen(),
        Homescreen.id : (context) =>  const Homescreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

i am also using a static String id in all my screens which is how i call from Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homescreen.id);

```
class Homescreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homescreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static String id = 'home_screen';
```

[I am using Flutter version: 2.8.1 and Dart Version 2.15.1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your RoundedButton widget:
Replace:

```dart
onPressed: () {
   press;
}
```

with

```dart
onPressed: press,
```

Edit:
For null safety

```dart
onPressed: () => press(),
```

In your code you're not `calling` the `press` function

Comment: it still doesnt like it. It gives me the error :he argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?':

Comment: See the edit above

Comment: i fixed it. I had to change final Function press;   to   final VoidCallback press;

thank you

Comment: ah just saw your update. Perfect. Thank you that worked.

Comment: Glad it worked! Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem